# CSS for disabled button using :not() to exclude a certain class

Tags: css

I have some button styling, which applies when the button has the `disabled` attribute.

However, I also have a `.loading` class that I'd like to apply to buttons.

I want the disabled styling to apply only if the button does not have the loading class.

Please see my JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pbcykx5L/

I'm imagining something like this, but it doesn't work. Is there a way of doing this?

```
.btn:not(.loading):disabled {
  background-color: #cdd9c3;
  border-color: #cdd9c3;
  text-shadow: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: You have the `.btn:disabled` style in the fiddle as well. Doesn't it work if you remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work. In your fiddle, there is no difference in the styles being applied to `.btn:not(.loading):disabled` and `.btn:disabled`. If you change the background color of one to red, you can see the CSS is being properly applied.

```css
.btn:disabled {
  background-color: #cdd9c3;
}
.btn:not(.loading):disabled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<button class="btn" disabled>Button (disabled)</button>
<button class="btn loading" disabled>Button (disabled and loading)</button>
```